# To-do app: foreign key usage Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm making a To-do application. I already made a register form, login form so a user can login to it's to do list now.
Now I want to make a to-do page where people can add to-do's.

Because this is the first time I do this in Laravel or even PHP actually, it's rather difficult to find out how I need to link the `FK_user_id` of my table `Tasks` to `PK_user_id` of my table `Users`.

Specific: 
Do I need to put the PK_user_id of the user that's logged in manually in the FK_user_id of my other table? Or is there an other way to do this?

Comment: Your question is very basic. Please read the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) and try to work it out on your own. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, my question is indeed basic. The problem is that it's very hard to explain. 

@SvenB: Where I am right now: I can insert the task I want into my database. The problem is: how can I link the users ID (PK) to the FK of my database table 'tasks'?

Because at this moment, the task I add is related to no user. It just stands there without FK.

Comment: Here's a guide that will help you understand the basics:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart

You should also be aware of the pros and cons of using an ORM:
https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-raw-SQL-versus-ORM-for-database-development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a **field** name into your **TASK** table as **user_id** . Then update your input form.

In your controller ,

```
$users = User::all();
//your functionalities
return Redirect::back()->with('users' , $users);  //Add others you need
```

Then the question , how can you insert the user ? so inside your **view.blade.php**

```
        <select name="news_type_id" id="" class="form-control">
              @foreach($users as $user)
                <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
              @endforeach
        </select>
```

This is the basic. Now if you have authentication system , then catch the logged user ID to do it. Thanks.